# Jquery UI dialog issue in firefox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

After submitting a request, a dialog box will appear with request Id and on clicking Ok button   it will redirect to output page. But if user clicks back button on browser, dialog box is coming. How to avoid this dialog box on click of back button?

Am not getting this issue in chrome but am getting this issue in firefox.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Browsers differ in how they reload pages when you use the back button, whether they reload the page or just restore it as it was when you navigated away. You should close the dialog before redirecting.

Comment: thanks barmar, my issue got resolved with your suggestion